# Trying to run an ANOVA for fields in a dataframe [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

So far my code looks like this:

```r
Points = readOGR(dsn = "./Data/filename.shp",layer = "layername",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
Points$LDI = extract(LDI, Points) 
LDI = raster("./Data/filename2.tif")
Points$LDI = extract(LDI, Points)
PointsDF = Points@data

for(i in PointsDF) { 
    Mod1 = lm(LDI ~ i, data = PointsDF) 
    Mod2 = lm(LDI ~ 1, data = PointsDF) 
    anova(Mod1, Mod2)
}
```

This last part is where I know I'm doing everything wrong. I want to run the anova on every numerical field in the data frame.

Comment: I don't have enough time to cast a proper answer. but your solution might be to use the apply() function instead of the loop. In R vectorisation is  preferable to a loop in general

Comment: I will give that a try! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.  A natural way is to loop over the field names.  Although there are many ways to do this, `lapply` is perhaps the most idiomatic because (a) it uses the field names (rather than field indexes, which can be dangerous) and (b) does not require pre-allocating any structures for the output.  The trick is to convert field names into formulas.  Again, there are many ways to do this, but a direct way is to assemble the formula as a string.

Here is working code as an example.  It produces a list of `anova` objects.

```
#
# Create some random data.
#
n <- 20
set.seed(17)
X <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(n), X1=runif(n), X2=1:n, X3=rexp(n))
#
# Loop over the regressors.
# (The base model can be precomputed.)
#
mod.0 <- lm(Y ~ 1, X)
models <- lapply(setdiff(names(X), "Y"), function(s) {
  mod.1 <- lm(as.formula(paste("Y ~", s)), X)
  anova(mod.0, mod.1)
})
print(models)
```

Here's the output, displaying this list of three `anova` results.

```
[[1]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Y ~ 1
Model 2: Y ~ X1
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq     F Pr(>F)
1     19 10.1157                          
2     18  9.6719  1   0.44385 0.826 0.3754

[[2]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Y ~ 1
Model 2: Y ~ X2
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
1     19 10.1157                              
2     18  8.1768  1     1.939 4.2684 0.05353 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

[[3]]
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Y ~ 1
Model 2: Y ~ X3
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     19 10.116                           
2     18 10.081  1  0.034925 0.0624 0.8056
```

As another example of working with what you have produced, here is `sapply` being used to print out their p-values:

```
sapply(models, function(m) m[["Pr(>F)"]][2])
```

> [1] 0.37542968 0.05352883 0.80562894

Comment: thank you for taking the time to correctly specify this analysis. I literally translated the corrections to the op's code and didn't feel compelled to correct the analysis.

Comment: This helped a lot (although now I'm getting an error about not being the same size of dataset). I think this is definitely what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not telling the loop what it is iterating on, defing a formula object in the anova call nor creating an object to store results.

In this example the "ij" variable is assigning to the list object and storing the anova models, "y" defined as a variable indicating the left-hand side of the model. The list object "anova.results" is storing each model. The index in the loop definition is using "which" to assign which column contains "y" and as such, drops it from the iterator. I am using the R "iris" dataset for the example.

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris[,-5]

y = "Sepal.Length"    
anova.results <- list()
ij=0
  for(i in names(iris)[-which(names(iris) == y)]) {
    ij = ij+1
    Mod = lm(stats::as.formula(paste(y, i, sep = "~")), data = iris) 
    anova.results[[ij]] <- anova(Mod, Mod)
  }
anova.results
```